# SAS Studio - How to utilise nested WHERE conditions for string searches

Tags: sas, where-clause, sas-macro, proc-sql, sas-studio

As part of a bigger project, I am trying to search through multiple tables for common columns. However I dont know the number of tables, number of columns or the exact names of columns so I cannot hard code the counts or names. My main issue is I am trying to search for a keyword from a list, in a long column name, such as Your_Email_Address using "Email". At the moment I can only get the column search working by listing each "NAME" search function individually (which isnt viable for this). I have tried numerous variations of `where NAME LIKE/contains(IN(&OPTIONS.))` but to no success. Does anyone know how to properly combine the `WHERE` functions so it will successfully search and select the column names for the containing keyword from the `&OPTIONS` list?  My code snippet so far is:

```
options mlogic mprint symbolgen;
%*LOOP;
%macro JOINWRAP;

%let OPTIONS = USERNAME
EMAIL
AGE
ETC...
;
%let dataset1 = A7;
%let dataset2 = Subset;
%let OPTIONS_count = %sysfunc(countw(&OPTIONS.));

%*read columns into macro variables;
%do j = 1 %to 2;
proc sql ;
    select NAME into :CLMNS&j SEPARATED BY ", " /*reading columns from each proc contents 
    into a seperate macro variable, so clmns1 = columns from A7*/
    from work.COLS&j /*cols1 = A7 PROC CONTENTS previously defined */
    where NAME CONTAINS "%scan(&OPTIONS.,1)" or NAME contains "%scan(&OPTIONS.,2)"
    ;
    quit;
%put &&CLMNS&j;
%end;
...
run;
/* %end; */
%mend JOINWRAP;
%JOINWRAP;
```

Comment: I cannot understand what it is that you want to combine.  Is the issue that you want to match names based on many different substrings?  If so that is probably much easier in a data step where you can have a DO loop.

Comment: To get a better answer explain in more detail what you are doing.  It is best not to attempt to use macro code to generate code until you know what code it is you need (and whether there is any need to generate code).

Comment: I have 2 separate tables and I have 5 target ID's eg #1 = email address, #2 = age etc... These columns (along with others) exist in each of the tables but have a different column name in each table. But they contain a common key word eg. Email_1 in table 1, but 2_Email in table 2.

I want to inner join the two email columns together and create an output table named EMAIL. I want to then repeat this for the other columns (age etc...) and end up with 5 results tables. So the main issue I'm facing is how to select & join the right columns from each table 1 & 2 without knowing the exact names.

Comment: I can do it when the cols are all in the same table, using the below.
`%let IDs = PP
FF
MM
SS
;

%let dataset = NON_EXACT;

%let ID_count = %sysfunc(countw(&IDs));

%do i=1 %to &ID_COUNT;

 %let CURRENT_ID = %scan(&IDs,&i);
 
proc sql NOPRINT;
 select NAME into :COL1 - :COL2 
 from work.COLS
 where NAME CONTAINS "&CURRENT_ID."
;
 quit;

proc sql;
create table &CURRENT_ID. as 
select row_num,  &COL1, &COL2
from &dataset`

Comment: So you want to DROP any variable that does not match the name pattern?

Comment: for this section yes. I'll re-add any dropped information later on using the unique row number. But for this process the more efficient the better. Though the ID's in the above comment should be email, age, user etc... the snippet was from another program

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to do something like:

```
data want;
  set contents;
  where upcase(name) contains 'EMAIL'
    or  upcase(name) contains 'USERNAME'
  ;
run;
```

If the list of substrings to search for is constant just hard code it.

If it varies then it will be much easier to do it with a DATA step than trying to force PROC SQL and/or macro language to do the work.

So something like this:

```
%let wordlist=EMAIL USERNAME;
data want;
  set contents;
  found=0;
  do index=1 to countw("&wordlist") until (found);
    if index(upcase(name),scan("&wordlist",index)) then found=1;
  end;
  if found;
run;
```

Comment: I am trying to do what your first data step does but the list isn't constant so cant be hard coded. Also I need to read the name values (which are the names of table columns from a previous PROC CONTENTS statement) into a macro variable to later reference them so I don't think a data step will work. As I need to generate tables using the column names and also later match the column values so need to be able to refer to them in the macro variable.

Comment: So table 1 has column named (email_1), and table X has column named (email_X). 

I have done a proc contents on each table so the results have the columns names. I then want to select columns containing "email" from tables' 1:X results and read them into a macro variable. Then I want to use the column names the macro values to create a new table containing columns email1:emailX

Comment: Once you have the list of names (and libref and member names) in a dataset you can use a data step to generate code to be run.   You could also use a data step to generate one or more macro variables.  But in general it is much easier to manipulate data using SAS code instead of macro code.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with data steps, but considering I have multiple "contents" tables to check (contents_1 -> contents_X) wont I need to wrap the data step in a macro to loop over the tables? Such as


```%macro loop;
%do X= 1 %to 5;

data want_&X
set contents_&X
run;

%end;
%mend;
%loop
```

Comment: Or are you referring to the fact it will be easier to scan and select the relevant data using a data step? 

Would I read the values into a macro variable using some sort Call SYMPUT function in the data step?

Comment: It looks like CALL SYMPUT only allows for 1 value in the macro variable and I am aiming for macro variable "EMAILS" to contain the values of (Email_1, Email 2, Email_X)

Comment: Don't generate the macro variable until you have all of the values.  One easy way to generate a delimited list of values into a macro variable is using the INTO clause with the SEPARATED BY option on PROC SQL.   `select name into :name_list separated by ' ' from have;`